# How to check if I'm logged in with current version of facebook login?

Tags: android, facebook-login

I have 2 activities:

1. MainActivity
2. FacebookLoginActivity

I followed current tutorial and my facebook login seems to work, but I have no idea how I can make use of it in my MainActivity.

When my application starts (or MainActivity) I want to check if user is logged in. If not - I want to start FacebookLoginActivity.

There are so many tutorials "how to implement facebook login", but I cant find any with "how to determine if user is logged in".

In old version I was just checking if `Session` object is null. In current version there is no such thing as `Session`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, You use Facebook api 4.0

You can use AccessToken object for checking user logged in or not.
Because Facebook creates a session After logged in and It keeps it session in Sharedprefences.

Example code.

```
 AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if( accessToken != null )
            System.out.println( "User Logged in" );
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using API 4.0, I was not sure about this, because facebook manual page says 2.3.